# Proof of the inequality $(2n/\textrm{log}n -1)/\sqrt{n} \geq \textrm{log} n$ for sufficiently large n?

Tags: inequality, algorithms, functional-inequalities

I found this inequality in CLRS (Coreman)(Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition), on Page - 137 . I can't understand the idea behind the proof.It would be really helpful if  someone could provide the proof with proper explanation.

Comment: You want to prove that $[(2n/\log n -1)/\sqrt{n}]/ \log n \ge 1$ for sufficiently large $n$. In fact, a stronger statement is true: $\lim_{n\to\infty} [(2n/\log n -1)/\sqrt{n}]/ \log n = \infty$. Can you see why that is a stronger statement? Can you prove that statement (using differential calculus)?

Comment: @GregMartin , yes the 2nd inequality really helped !